# Does a request with Status 304 ping a website's server the same as a Status 200?

Tags: python, web, server, python-requests, http-status-codes

I am wanting to create an RSS Feed streamer to get news in real time as the feed is updated. I don't want to be too much of a nuisance to the website by constantly sending requests every couple minute or so. I was wondering if I stored the etag and last modified, and only returned data when status != 304, would the 304 statuses from the requests where RSS data hasnt changed cause the same strain on the server as constant 200 statuses. Essentially my question is, does the server/website pick up my requests with 304 statuses or do they only see my requests with 200 status where the request succeeded?

Comment: If I'm reading your post correctly, I have the feeling that if you are in some way sending a request to a remote server, the remote server might be noticing each request regardless of the status code returned (200 or 304). When you get a status code back from the remote server, I think it usually means that the server noticed your request and is responding in some manner. The remote server might have to do more processing work (depending on the related software application it is running) for different situations, but I don't know much about this particular remote server.

Comment: My understanding is that the server receives the request, checks the ETag and last-modified headers then returns a 304 HTTP response if the data has not changed otherwise returns a 200 HTTP response with data. Servers I use add these 304 responses to their logs. So yes, the server responds to the request in both cases

Comment: Do you know if the 304 response would count as a pageview on a website? @Dan-Dev

Comment: @mattwatkins it depends upon how the pageview software works but I would guess yes it does in most cases

Comment: Cool, thank you! @Dan-Dev